# SQL statements in separate file

Tags: .net, sql

I'm working on .net project and writing an application that interacts with database.  I currently have some SQL statements in the code and I want to put these statements in separate file with solution.  So, later when the application gets deployed, and if I want to update SQL statements, I could just update the statements in the file and just replace the file instead of redeploying the whole solution.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What kind of database are you using? If it supports Procedures consider using that.

Comment: you could use a resource file in the project.

Comment: So, what's your question? How to write the file? How to run the commands in the file?

Comment: Just a side-note - be careful you don't end up building a handy SQL-Injection mechanism by mistake ! (Don't want people over-writing your SQL commands with 'DROPs' and 'DELETEs' I mean ! :)

Answer (score 2):

What kind of sql statements are these? Perhaps, you could use stored procedures and call them from your .net code.

Comment: These are a couple of long select statements.

Comment: In that case you could benefit from using stored procedures. Stored procedures perform faster than running a normal sql query

Answer (score 1):

Just don't loose sight of the fact that if you deploy this application with the SQL statements publicly accessible you open up your database to any user with a text editor. Anybody could open up that file and change a `"SELECT * FROM Products"` to `"DELETE FROM Products"` and your products are gone. Of course, you may be able to protect your database if you only grant `SELECT` permissions to the application in the database but still.. it seems like a bad idea to leave your queries out in the open like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the SQL statements in an XML file, then use `System.Xml.Linq` to read the file.

However, you should use stored procedures instead.

Comment: Then you should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.

Answer (score 0):

If you like your db functionality easy to modify you should consider using stored procedures. This has also some security benefits.

Answer (score 0):

why not implement them as stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

We do this very often where I work by using the App.config file. Create an app.config file for your project and add key-value pairs for each of the sql statements. For example:

```
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
  <add key="PRODUCTS_QUERY" value="SELECT * FROM Products"></add>
  <add key="EMPLOYEE_QUERY" value="SELECT * FROM Employee"></add>
 </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then, in your code, you can pull the queries from the file using something like this (for VB.NET):

```
Dim myReader As New System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader
Dim productsQuery As String = myReader.GetValue("PRODUCTS_QUERY", GetType(System.String))
Dim employeeQuery As String = myReader.GetValue("EMPLOYEE_QUERY", GetType(System.String))
```

But note - the App.config file gets compiled into a ProjectName.exe.config file in the bin folder - this is the file that you should change if you want to change the SQL without rebuilding.

**Edit:**
You can also try using an xml file and then parsing with XPath. It's very powerful and very easy. Check out one of these tutorials:

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/

http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

We have done this in the past using XML much like a config file, with a key="SomeProcName" and a value="the SQL".

When doing this we have found two complications:

1. You have to be very careful about escaping special characters - quotes get confusing sometimes.
2. You will want to check performance, as sometimes this technique can have a negative impact on query caching.

Answer (score 0):

you may use SqlCommand (OleDbCommand if RDBMS is not Sql Server) to execute sql statements. 
[running .sql file using C#](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/511946-running-sql-file-using-c)